# Количество уникальных товаров в корзине товара opencart

Tags: opencart, корзина, ocstore

Как в корзине реализовать подсчет количество уникальных товаров. Т.е. Если заказывают 3 телефона, 2 планшета и 1 мяч - мне нужно знать, что это 3 позиции, а не 6 товаров.

ocStore 2.1

Comment: Приведите пример кода в котором вы пытаетесь это определить или того участка в который вы планируете вставить свой код. Здесь помогают решить проблему, а не решают за Вас.

Answer (score 0):

Какой вопрос такой ответ.

Вам нужно группировать в корзине товары с одинаковыми `ID`, выводить один товар с `ID` и количество

Без кода, другого ответа не ждите